# Finding multiple column names in multiple views in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view

I have 40 columns (including some column which are like *'1' Order* ) to be searched in 16 different views.

I tried the below query but again the automation of the process could be much better.

```
/*
Some TYPE values that can be used:
P - Stored procedure
U - User defined table
FN - Scalar function
IF - Inline Table Valued function
TF - Multi statement table value function
V - View
*/
SELECT schem.name AS 'Schema', obj.name AS 'Object', obj.type
FROM sys.objects AS obj
INNER JOIN syscomments AS comms ON obj.object_id = comms.id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS schem ON obj.schema_id = schem.schema_id
WHERE obj.type IN ('V')
  AND comms.text LIKE '%TEXT_TO_LOOK_FOR%'
ORDER BY obj.name
```

Can someone please help for providing input of multiple columns and to search in multiple specific views?

Comment: Why not look at sys.columns?

Comment: Do you want to find columns in the view, or columns USED in views? syscomments shouldn't be used in either way, because they are broken up in multiple parts. Check out sys.sql_modules instead

Comment: You might wanna check out sys.sql_expression_dependencies which contains references between objects

Comment: Reading this again I think I misunderstood the question. Are you trying to search through 16 different views to find  certain data?

Comment: @SeanLange yes. 40 specific columns in 16 specific views

Comment: So you want to search 40 columns in 16 different views for a specific value in the data? The performance of that is going to be horrific. Unless all 40 columns are in each view this is going to require dynamic sql. I think you need to provide a clearer explanation of what you want to accomplish. Also probably need to provide some table structures, view definitions etc so people can work on your query.

Comment: @SeanLange yes i want to achieve the same but this will not be used everyday. mostly once in 6 months or an year. Hence performance is not an issue

Comment: OK. Then provide some details about what you want to do so others can help you with the query.

Comment: @SeanLange basically i want to search a column value in 16 views. for each view i want to find if that column is used or not(basically find text ) and kind of print exists or not for every view . then i want to do the same for all 40 columns.  how to automate this thing ??

Comment: Your explanation is too vague. Provide the definition of a couple of views and what you expect as output given those definitions.